# Normalise numbers in nested list

Tags: python

I'm trying to normilise the second item in the below list to 1. I can do this if the list only has numbers in a single list as follows

```
rank = [['a', 234],['b',435],['c',567]]

ranking = [float(i)/sum(rank) for i in rank]
```

However when the list has a second item and is nested this fails with

```
ranking = [float(i[1])/sum(rank) for i[1] in rank]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the "nested" list you are refering to? I'm not sure to be understanding it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function call `sum(rank)`will attempt to sum up all members of the `rank` list. When they are not numbers (e.g. lists), this will fail.

You need to calculate the normalizer by making a sum of the list elements, e.g. like this:

```
normalizer=sum([e[1] for e in rank])
```

(also, calculating the normalizer for every list member is bad coding practice).

Here's the fixed code:

```
rank = [['a', 234],['b',435],['c',567]]
normalizer=sum([e[1] for e in rank])
ranking=[float(e[1])/normalizer for e in rank]
```

Comment: just this: awesome first answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Jean-FrançoisFabre!

Answer (score 2):

you have to consider the second item of the sublist when performing computations

```
rank = [['a', 234],['b',435],['c',567]]

ranking = [[i[0],i[1]/sum(r[1] for r in rank)] for i in rank]

print(ranking)
```

result

```
[['a', 0.18932038834951456], ['b', 0.35194174757281554], ['c', 0.4587378640776699]]
```

note that this is one liner but not very efficient since `sum(r[1] for r in rank)` is recomputed every time. You could compute it first, then use it in your list comprehension.